# Correct Way of Email format Validation in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

hi friends i need correct email format validation, and in my code

```
+ (BOOL)validateEmailID:(NSString *)emailString {
    if ([emailString length] == 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    NSString *regExPattern = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    NSRegularExpression *regEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:regExPattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSUInteger regExMatches = [regEx numberOfMatchesInString:emailString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [emailString length])];
    return regExMatches != 0;
}
```

Its working fine. but am entered email id like -  123@123.com & bala@gmail.com & 12bala@123.com its working good. 
but my question is first value should be character then number or full character email id validation: 
i want email entered like bala777@gmail.com or test@hr7.com or test07@gmail2.com this format. not only full numbers. 
mixed email id but first entered value is should be character.

please someone can help.

Comment: Good article http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: In general, email addresses cannot be perfectly validated through regular expression. I would advise to use a generic `^\\S+@\\S+$`. Everything else is not needed. Validation should protect the user from entering bad data (e.g. fullname into email). It doesn't have to be perfect and emails have too many  edge cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the code

```
+(BOOL)validateEmailWithstring:(NSString*)mailString
{
     NSString *validString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
     NSPredicate *emailTest=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",validString];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:mailString];
}
```

Comment: thanks @Arun, its working but not exactly what i want .if you enter like 123@123.com its answer is error. that's exactly want bro.first entered value should be character like test07@test.com. not this 123@test.com or 123@123.com.

Comment: So, you want this to work - t123@test.com. What should be the starting minimum character user should enter ?

Comment: Replace - valid string -                                                                          `validString = "[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9-].+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*"`  Change {1} - to number of minimum character you want to be entered as string.

Comment: I Edited the string Value @Arun.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
-(BOOL)isValidEmail
{
    BOOL stricterFilter = YES;
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{1,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@.+\\.[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For worldwide:

```
+(BOOL)validateEmail:(NSString *)mailStr {

     NSString *validStr = @"/^(\w)+(\.\w+)*@(\w)+((\.\w+)+)$/";
     NSPredicate *emailPre = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",validStr];
     return [emailPre evaluateWithObject:mailStr];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func validateEmail(candidate: String) -> Bool {
 let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
 return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluateWithObject(candidate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression, that you are using does not satisfy the RFC 5322 so you are blocking many domains, like every company in the UK (example@company.co.uk).

```
+ (BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) candidate;
{
    // The Official Standard: RFC 5322
    // http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html
    NSString *emailRegEx =
    @"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}"
    @"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"
    @"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-"
    @"z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"
    @"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"
    @"9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"
    @"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
    return [predicate evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Accordint to [this](http://emailregex.com) site:

I added prefix to the method of NSString category according to Apple recomendations.

```
@interface NSString(RegularExpressions)

- (BOOL)rep_isValidEmail;

@end

@implementation

- (BOOL)rep_isValidEmail
{
    NSString *expression = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}";
         NSPredicate *test=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",expression];
        return [test evaluateWithObject:self];
}
@end
```